# C# detecting text on image and moving them within a bitmap

Tags: c#, text, bitmap

So the problem i'm having in my c# project i'm making is that i want to move text within an image. The problem is that i can't seem to find a way to detect text with an image let alone move a specific line of that text within the image.

Is there way to first detect all the text that is present in the image and once you know the text or position of in within the image to move the line within an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is called "OCR" for "Optical character recognition".

Use Tesseract (you can get it on NuGet) and do something like that

```
    using tessnet2;  
    using System.Drawing;  
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;  
    using System.Drawing.Imaging; 

    // now add the following C# line in the code page  
    var image = new Bitmap(@"Z:\NewProject\demo\image.bmp");  
    var ocr = new Tesseract();  
    ocr.Init(@ "Z:\NewProject\How to use Tessnet2 library\C#\tessdata", "eng", false);  
    var result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);  
    foreach(tessnet2.Word word in result)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(word.Text);  
    }
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Please make sure to mark this as answer if this solved your issue ;)

Comment: it did solve the problem i'm having only i've been asked to perform in in another way but this gave me the fundamentals to fixing the problem

Comment: Ask another question, DLP. I'd be glad to help you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I did the following which worked: (I used [IronOcr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronOcr))

```
var image = new Bitmap(@"urfile.png");
IronTesseract varocr = new IronTesseract();
varocr.Language = OcrLanguage.English;
var mytext = varocr.Read(image);
Console.WriteLine(mytext.Text);
```